# Как в .NET Core установить другой уровень ведения логов

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, логирование

Не могу понять — вроде делаю всё правильно. Но почему то в логи .NET Core пишет сообщения уровня `Information`. Хотя я явно указал в настройках писать только `Error`.
Вот часть `Program.cs`:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        })
        .Build();
```

Конфиг `appsettings.json` выглядит так:

```
"Logging": {
  "IncludeScopes": false,
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Error"
  }
}
```

Что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: А если попробовать задать (можно даже без `appsettings.json`) просто `.ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Error))`?

Comment: Vadim Ovchinnikov, попробовал ваш вариант, и увы тоже не помогает, это мистика какая то, я весь код касающийся логов из этого проекта, скопировал в другой проект и там все ок, а тут какая то беда..

Comment: Может быть это связано с тем что в этом проекте у меня есть сервис Mvc  а в другой проект создан на основе пустого шаблона?

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov Это видимо какая-то проблема с проектом и это не связано с предоставленным кодом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался...
Причина была в том, что в директории приложения был файл `appsettings.Development.json` и настройки логгирования брались из него а не из `appsettings.json`, причем этот фал в обозревателе VisualStudio не было видно, а я и не догадался сам сходить в директорию приложения и посмотреть что там есть.

Откуда этот файл и кто его создал непонятно.